# Django Forms new foreignkey record

Tags: django

I'd like to present a `charfield` for the user's Locality and if it already exists, use that `foreignkey`. If it doesn't exist, create a new record and use that `foreignkey`. It should be completely transparent to the user that the `charfield` is selecting an existing row or creating a new row. Is there built-in functionality for this, or does it have to be created in `view.py`?

Solution:

views.py

```python
    place, created = Place.objects.get_or_create(
        street_number = form.cleaned_data['street_number'],
        route = Route.objects.get_or_create(
            route = form.cleaned_data['route'],
            neighborhood = Neighborhood.objects.get_or_create(
                neighborhood = form.cleaned_data['neighborhood'],
                locality = Locality.objects.get_or_create(
                    locality = form.cleaned_data['locality'],
                    administrative_area_level_1 = form.cleaned_data['administrative_area_level_1']
                )[0]
            )[0]
        )[0]
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't be too hard to do in a `ModelForm`.  You'd just override `ModelForm.save()`:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    if not commit:
        raise NotImplementedException('commit=False is not supported yet')

    super(MyModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    ZipCode.objects.get_or_create(zipcode=self.instance.zipcode)

    return self.instance
```

Comment: `get_or_create` is what I was looking for, this would streamline my logic, thanks. The problem now is how to apply this logic before validation occurs? Right now if I submit the form, crispy gives _Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices._ Additionally, could you please check `forms.py` in the OP and tell me if it's correct, and what should go in `view.py`?

Comment: Got it, thanks for the tip. Updated OP with solution code.